# "Is that the words?!" or "are those the words?!" when forgetting the lyrics of a song

Tags: grammar, informal-language

I was watching a  video and I heard the following sentence:

> We're gonna take you on a
> journey here today, literally I'm about to call this guy, the scammer,
> up, and we'll be watching him, *[music playing]* every step he takes,
> every move he makes, every single day, every time he prays. *[music
> stops]* **Is that the words?!**

I'm wondering why he said *is that* and not *are those*.
Is this natural in speaking?

Comment: No - he's mostly "quoting" the lyrics from [The Police - *Every Breath You Take*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMOGaugKpzs). And at the end wondering how accurately he recited the words. Where it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to ask ***Is that** [what I just said, considered as a "whole"] correct?* or ***Are those** [words] correct?*

Comment: (I mean what he said before *Is that the words?* isn't "natural", obviously. It's a stylised context-relevant recitation. But it's perfectly natural to use either ***Is that...*** OR ***Are those...*** for his question at the end,)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Is that [what I just said, considered as a "whole"] correct?" makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Moha, you should remember that using a question mark and exclamation mark together like this `?!` is not done in standard English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks a lot for pointing that out.